# Login with VueJS and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, authentication

I create a login form by VueJS. I can get user information to VueJS after logging. But it doesn't logged to Laravel system. I create API for login function

```
public function login()
{
    // SOME CODE to check email/password here
    if( Auth::attempt(['email' => request('username'), 'password' =>request('password')], request('remember'))) {



        // Format the final response in a desirable format
        return response()->json([


            'status' => 200,
            'authUser'=> Auth::user()
        ]);
    }else {

            return response()->json([
                'error' => true,
                'message' => 'Not correct'
            ], 200);
    }
}
```

Auth::attempt still works because I tried to return 'authUser'=> Auth::user() then I got user data in console. 
But it doesn't logged to Laravel system. It seems two sessions are different. How can I logged to Laravel by VueJS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used CSRF-TOKEN?

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to add Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
 in app.js file. But no luck!

Comment: Is your route in the middleware web? because if isn't the api routes doesn't have session to keep the state of login.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;

// Creating a token with scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['place-orders'])->accessToken;
```

[Check here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens)